# Combining two columns in a data frame and creating a new column in an existing data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to combine information from multiple data frames.  Suppose I have a master data frame called "master" regarding information about a bunch of cars.  The Master data frame has ALL IDs possible.   Then suppose I have 2 other data frames, each with SOME of the ids and the color of the cars but not all.  I want to put all of the colors of the cars, corresponding to their IDs in the existing Master data frame.

Master df looks like this:

```
 id     year
 4D     2005
 5A     2003    
 7T     1999
 8Q     2001
 3G     1998
 6N     2009
 2B     2013
```

df1 looks like this:

```
id     color
5A     black
7T     green
8Q     gold
4D     white
```

df2 looks like this:

```
id     color
5A     NA
6N     purple
3G     NA
2B     orange
```

Here's the code to make the 4 data frames:

```
master <- data.frame(id = c("4D", "5A", "7T", "8Q", "3G", "6N", "2B"), year=c(2005,2003,1999,2001,1998,2009,2013))
df1 <- data.frame(id=c("5A", "7T", "8Q", "4D"), color=c("black", "green", "gold", "white"))
df2 <- data.frame(id=c("5A", "6N", "3G", "2B"), color=c(NA,"purple", NA, "orange"))
```

I want the final master data frame to look like this:

```
 id     year     color
 4D     2005     white
 5A     2003     black    
 7T     1999     green
 8Q     2001     gold
 3G     1998     NA
 6N     2009     purple
 2B     2013     orange
```

If there is value in one data frame and an NA in the other data frame for the same ID (ie: ID 5A has "black" in df1 but NA in df2), the value should be present in the spreadsheet.

Any thoughts?  I've looked at the merge and stack functions but I don't think these are the ways to go about it?

Comment: Is your line 6 correct? 6N-2009-NA. Why NA?

Comment: This is merely an example of a real-life problem I am working on.  In some tables there are NA values even if in another table there is an actual value for the same ID.

Comment: An ID with `6N` should be "purple" in the final master data.frame though as `df2` has the `6N/purple` combination.

Comment: And 4D only has white

Comment: Well, you should not add values arbitrarily there. You should provide the exact expected output.

Comment: I found my typo, thanks for catching it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- Master
df1
df2

dft <- rbind(df1, df2)

df3 <- dft[with(dft, order(id, color)), ]
df3 <- df3[!duplicated(df3$color), ]
merge(df, df3, by = 'id', all.x = T)

  id year  color
1 2B 2013 orange
2 3G 1998   <NA>
3 4D 2005  white
4 5A 2003  black
5 6N 2009 purple
6 7T 1999  green
7 8Q 2001   gold
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option.
1, My approach is to combine df1 and df2 first then remove those color is NA using `complete.cases` 
2, Then merge master with the new df3. (`all=TRUE`, ensure those id not included in df3 will shown up in the combined data.frame)

```
df3 <- rbind(df1,df2)                      #row combine for df1 and df2
df3 <- df3[complete.cases(df3),]           #remove row with NA
merge(master, df3, by="id", all=TRUE)      #merge master and df3 based on id
```

Result is

```
  id year  color
1 2B 2013 orange
2 3G 1998   <NA>
3 4D 2005  white
4 5A 2003  black
5 6N 2009 purple
6 7T 1999  green
7 8Q 2001   gold
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `sqldf` package once you combine your `df1` and `df2` data frames by row:

*Assumes the same input from your example above (e.g. values for `master`, `df1`, `df2`)

```
> id_color <- rbind(df1, df2)

> library(sqldf)

> data <- sqldf("SELECT m.*, i.color FROM master m, id_color i WHERE m.id = i.id")

> data
  id year  color
1 4D 2005  white
2 5A 2003   <NA>
3 5A 2003  black
4 7T 1999  green
5 8Q 2001   gold
6 3G 1998   <NA>
7 6N 2009 purple
8 2B 2013 orange

> data <- sqldf("SELECT id, year, MIN(color) FROM data GROUP BY id, year") #removes duplicate with NULL

> data
  id year MIN(color)
1 2B 2013     orange
2 3G 1998       <NA>
3 4D 2005      white
4 5A 2003      black
5 6N 2009     purple
6 7T 1999      green
7 8Q 2001       gold
```